# List every AWS service I am using

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to list every service that I am using on AWS? EC2 instances, S3 buckets, Route53, etc. unsing the Java SDK?
If not, can each service describe itself (Region, status and so on)?

Comment: Sorry, I strongly suspect the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single call you could make, but you always call each of describe calls.

If you're trying to find out what you're using, I see two options:

- enable detailed billing, and process the billing logs.  This will give you a list of everything you're getting charged for.
- enable cloud trail.  This won't help with existing objects, but any new objects will have records.

Comment: Well, a describe for each service it is, then. My current setup right now is to set the region and see if the describe call returns something. This way, I can find out, which region has what active service.